# Paypal Rest API Advisory needed

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

This is my first time to integrate e-commerce website with paypal api.

I found many source code about paypal integration with form post method.

What I'm looking for is;

1. When user signup, they will input their paypal billing information (on our website or paypal website).
2. When user get service from the website, they will be automatically charged from their paypal account.(which means transfer amount from user's paypal account to our business account)
3. The amount varies depending on the service they get. Which means, recurring payment can not be applied.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, it just depends how you are wanting it work exactly. You could do this a few different ways. If you are needing assistance with PayPal API's I would recommend you check out http://www.ccaples.com/index.php/api-s and if you hover over API's there is a ton of great samples you can download.

One way you can accomplish what you are wanting is to setup the transaction as an authorization for an amount and then once you capture the amount, you will be able to adjust the amount depending on the service.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I checked the page, but I cant exactly find the example code there. They just listed the APIs. Could you give me more detail on it?

Comment: You will want to have an API call to send an authorizatio, ie:
`TRXTYPE=A`

Comment: Also there are example codes here [http://www.ccaples.com/index.php/misc/tools-and-stuff/downloads](http://www.ccaples.com/index.php/misc/tools-and-stuff/downloads)